# Why the length of the array appended in loop is more than the number of iteration?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, append

I ran this code and expected an array size of 10000 as `time` is a numpy array of length of 10000.

```
freq=np.empty([])
for i,t in enumerate(time):
    freq=np.append(freq,np.sin(t))
print(time.shape)
print(freq.shape)
```

But this is the output I got

```
(10000,)
(10001,)
```

Can someone explain why I am getting this disparity?

Comment: Did you look at a simpler `np.append` case, such as `np.append(np.empty([]),1)`?  That produces a (2,) array.  Don't use `np.append`.  It's playing games with your inputs that you don't understand.  And it's inefficient when used in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the function `np.empty()` returns an uninitialized array of a given shape. Hence, when you do `np.empty([])`, it returns an uninitialized array as `array(0.14112001)`. It's like having a value "ready to be used", but without having the actual value. You can check this out by printing the variable `freq` before the loop starts.

So, when you loop over `freq = np.append(freq,np.sin(t))` this actually initializes the array and append a second value to it.

Also, if you just need to create an empty array just do `x = np.array([])` or `x = []`.

You can read more about this numpy.empty function here:

https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html

And more about initializing arrays here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_13.1.3/com.ibm.xlc1313.aix.doc/language_ref/aryin.html

I'm not sure if I was clear enough. It's not a straight forward concept. So please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should fill np.empty(0).

I look for source code of numpy [numpy/core.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/19efe2199845d1ba5464795eed89a347c70d22d8/numpy/matlib.py#L24)

```
def empty(shape, dtype=None, order='C'):
"""Return a new matrix of given shape and type, without initializing entries.
Parameters
----------
shape : int or tuple of int
    Shape of the empty matrix.
dtype : data-type, optional
    Desired output data-type.
order : {'C', 'F'}, optional
    Whether to store multi-dimensional data in row-major
    (C-style) or column-major (Fortran-style) order in
    memory.
See Also
--------
empty_like, zeros
Notes
-----
`empty`, unlike `zeros`, does not set the matrix values to zero,
and may therefore be marginally faster.  On the other hand, it requires
the user to manually set all the values in the array, and should be
used with caution.
Examples
--------
>>> import numpy.matlib
>>> np.matlib.empty((2, 2))    # filled with random data
matrix([[  6.76425276e-320,   9.79033856e-307], # random
        [  7.39337286e-309,   3.22135945e-309]])
>>> np.matlib.empty((2, 2), dtype=int)
matrix([[ 6600475,        0], # random
        [ 6586976, 22740995]])
"""
return ndarray.__new__(matrix, shape, dtype, order=order)
```

It will input first arg shape into ndarray, so it will init a new array as [].

And you can print `np.empty(0)` and  `freq=np.empty([])` to see what are their differences.

Comment: I think his use of `np.append` is more of a problem than the use of `np.empty`.  But the OP is using both `np.empty([])` and `np.append` in a naively list like fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to replicate a list operation:

```
freq=[]
for i,t in enumerate(time):
     freq.append(np.sin(t))
```

But neither `np.empty` or `np.append` are exact clones; the names are similar but the differences are significant.

First:

```
In [75]: np.empty([])                                                                                  
Out[75]: array(1.)
In [77]: np.empty([]).shape                                                                            
Out[77]: ()
```

This is a 1 element, 0d array.

If you look at the code for `np.append` you'll see that if the 1st argument is not 1d (and axis is not provided) it `flattens` it (that's documented as well):

```
In [78]: np.append??                                                                                   
In [82]: np.empty([]).ravel()                                                                          
Out[82]: array([1.])
In [83]: np.empty([]).ravel().shape                                                                    
Out[83]: (1,)
```

It is not a 1d, 1 element array.  Append that with another array:

```
In [84]: np.append(np.empty([]), np.sin(2))                                                            
Out[84]: array([1.        , 0.90929743])
```

The result is 2d.  Repeat that 1000 times and you end up with 1001 values.

`np.empty` despite its name does not produce a `[]` list equivalent.  As others show `np.array([])` sort of does, as would `np.empty(0)`.

`np.append` is not a list append clone.  It is just a cover function to `np.concatenate`.  It's ok for adding an element to a longer array, but beyond that it has too many pitfalls to be useful. It's especially bad in a loop like this.  Getting a correct start array is tricky.  And it is slow (compared to list append).  Actually these problems apply to all uses of `concatenate` and `stack...` in a loop.